# Dozer InstantiationException mapping Calendar class

Tags: java, dozer

I'm getting an InstantiationException when trying to map Date -> Calendar.

Simple test follows:

```
    @Test
    public void testConversion()
    {
        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2009, 2, 3);
        Date sourceValue = cal.getTime();
        DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
        Object result = mapper.map(sourceValue, Calendar.class);
    }
```

According to the [docs](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/faq.html#datatype-conversions), this is supported out of the box (even though Calendar is abstract).  Anyone got experience with this and able to point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what's the result of the test?

Comment: It throws an InstantiationException on the mapper.map() line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. This throws `InstantionException` (I consider this a bug in dozer. Will you file it in their bug tracking system?).

However. It works when you convert the Date <--> Calendar values not on the root level. This test works for me (dozer 5.1):

```
    public static class Source {
        private Date value;
        public void setValue(Date value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        public Date getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public static class Target {
        private Calendar value;
        public void setValue(Calendar value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        public Calendar getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }


    @Test
    public void testConversion()
    {
        final GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2009, 2, 3);
        Source source = new Source(){{ setValue(cal.getTime());}};

        DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
        Target result = (Target) mapper.map(source, Target.class);
        assertEquals(cal.getTimeInMillis(), result.getValue().getTimeInMillis());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I may have to look at doing this dynamically with a little proxy magic.

Bug filed : https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2855016&group_id=133517&atid=727368

Answer (score 1):

If you change Calendar.class to GregorianCalendar.class the test works.

Comment: I guess OP is totally aware of it.

Comment: Thanks - but the intent not to have to change destination class in order to do the conversion.  Ideally, I'd like to just apply my conversion code abstractly, with not a care in the world about what the destination class is...